# Active Campaign - Newsletter using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, activecampaign

I am getting an error when submitting my newsletter app using NodeJs. I can't even add the dummy data. I am still learning and appreciate if you can send any reference for my concern.

Please see code below

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");
const sdk = require('api')('@activecampaign/v3#19qi536gl58csf5q');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//BodyParser MiddleWare
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true}));

//Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

//sending the signup.html file to the browser as soon as a request is made on localhost port#
app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
 
app.post("/", (req,res) => { 
  const firstName = req.body.fName;
  const lastName = req.body.lName;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const baseUrl = "https://radmik1435080.api-us1.com/api/3/contacts";
  const apiKey = "x";
 


const sdk = require('api')('@activecampaign/v3#19qi536gl58csf5q');

const data = sdk['create-a-new-contact']({
  contact: {
    email: 'johndoe@example.com',
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    phone: '7223224241',
    fieldValues: [
      {
        field: '1',
        value: 'The Value for First Field'
      },
      {field: '6', value: '2008-01-20'}
    ]
  }
}, {
  'Api-Token': 'x'
})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err)); 
 
  
  
}); 


app.post("/err", (req,res) => {
  res.redirect("/");
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port} `);
});
```

This is the error message
https://pastebin.com/yAHk6Qsp

Thanks in advance.